# Instance variable in another class in Android

Tags: java, android

I seems having an issue where an instance variable is not updated in MainAtivity. the text still show "testing" instead of the message received by onMessage()

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



    pacioWebSocketListener myWS = new pacioWebSocketListener();
    private String pacioMsg = myWS.getPacioMsg();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

        TextView tv = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        tv.setText("Message: " + pacioMsg);
```

And here is the pacioWebsocketListener.java

```
public class pacioWebSocketListener extends WebSocketListener {

private static final int NORMAL_CLOSURE_STATUS = 1000;
WebSocket ws;
public String pacioMsg = "testing";

public void setPacioMsg(String paciomsg){
    pacioMsg = paciomsg;
}

public String getPacioMsg(){
    return pacioMsg;
}
@Override
public void onOpen(WebSocket webSocket, Response response) {
    super.onOpen(webSocket, response);
    Log.v(TAG,"onOpen");
}

@Override
public void onMessage(WebSocket webSocket, String message) {
    super.onMessage(webSocket, message);
    setPacioMsg(message);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your activity, you are getting the value of pacioMsg before its value is changed by the method onMessage. onMessage is not called when you instantiate pacioWebSocketListener, it's only called in the event of a new message

So, If you want your activity to know every time a message arrives and update its textview, you need to find a way to make your activity and your class pacioWebSocketListener communicate.

You can do it by creating an Interface Listener like this:

in your class pacioWebSocketListener, create an interface

```
public class pacioWebSocketListener extends WebSocketListener {

   MessageListener msgListener; 

  private static final int NORMAL_CLOSURE_STATUS = 1000;
  WebSocket ws;


  public pacioWebSocketListener(MessageListener listener){
       this.msgListener = listener;
  }

  // interface
  public interface MessageListener{
     void onMessageReceived(String message)
  }


  @Override
  public void onOpen(WebSocket webSocket, Response response) {
    super.onOpen(webSocket, response);
    Log.v(TAG,"onOpen");
  }

  @Override
  public void onMessage(WebSocket webSocket, String message) {
    super.onMessage(webSocket, message);

    // When a new Message arrives , call the MessageListener.onMessageReceived
    msgListener.onMessageReceived(message);
  }
```

Now, in your activity implements the interface created in the pacioWebSocketListener class and override the method onMessageReceived, it goes like this

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements pacioWebSocketListener.MessageListener {


    TextView  tv;  



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

        // Pass "this" in the constructor, to show that this activity is
        // Listening for changes   
        pacioWebSocketListener myWS = new pacioWebSocketListener(this);

        tv = findViewById(R.id.textView);
     }
 // Override the method in MessageListener Inteface
 public void onMessageReceived(String message){
          // Then from here you can update your UI
          tv.setText("Message: " + message);
 }
```

Now Every time a new message arrives, your TextView will be updated with the text

Comment: thank for the help, however, I got error on this line:                          pacioWebSocketListener myWS = new pacioWebSocketListener(this); pacioWebSocketListerner() in pacioWebsocketListener cannot be applied to mainActivity